# Differentiating the Free Energy for the Chemical Potential

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

I wanted to ask a question about the partial differential of the Free Energy equation.

I learnt to prove the Free Energy equation:

> \begin{aligned} \frac{F\left(N_{A}, N_{B}\right)}{k T}=& N_{A} \ln \left(\frac{N_{A}}{N}\right)+N_{B} \ln \left(\frac{N_{B}}{N}\right) \\ &+\left(\frac{z w_{A A}}{2 k T}\right) N_{A}+\left(\frac{z w_{B B}}{2 k T}\right) N_{B}+\chi_{A B} \frac{N_{A} N_{B}}{N} \end{aligned}

and then also learnt about the derivative

> $$\mu_{A}=\left(\frac{\partial F} {\partial N_{A}}\right)_{T, N_{B}}$$

where $N$ is the total number of molecules in the mixture, $N_A$ is the number of molecules of type A and $N_B$ is the number of molecules of type B such that

$$N = N_A + N_B$$

so I tried to differentiate the equation above using this idea:

$$\frac{\mu_{A}}{k T}=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial N_{A}}\left(\frac{F}{k T}\right)\right]_{T, N_{B}}$$

$$=\ln \left(\frac{N_{A}}{N}\right)+1-\frac{N_{A}}{N}-\frac{N_{B}}{N}+\frac{z w_{A A}}{2 k T}+\chi_{A B} \frac{\left(N_{A}+N_{B}\right) N_{B}-N_{A} N_{B}}{\left(N_{A}+N_{B}\right)^{2}}$$

but I couldn't get past the second term.

I could prove the terms

$$\ln \left(\frac{N_{A}}{N}\right) + 1$$

as it was the "product rule" applied on

$$N_{A} \ln \left(\frac{N_{A}}{N}\right)$$

and the rest of the differential apart from

$$-\frac{N_{A}}{N}-\frac{N_{B}}{N}$$

Where do these terms come from?

This derivation taken from [here](https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/1397241/download?download_frd=1&verifier=TXNeVt5gwcRtjyBV5VRpx8qJDipyqUOnPqmjHw1V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the $N$ in the logarithm. Since $N_{B}$ is kept constant while changing $N_{A}$, the total number of particles $N=N_{A}+N_{B}$ changes as well. The missing term is

$$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial N}\left[N_{A}\ln\left(\dfrac{N_{A}}{N}\right)+N_{B}\ln\left(\dfrac{N_{B}}{N}\right)\right]=-\dfrac{N_{A}}{N}-\dfrac{N_{B}}{N}$$

Comment: Hi there! I'm just a bit confused because I'm new to this area of thermodynamics. So you're saying that because N is also changing as I'm keeping $N_B$ constant, I need to use the chain rule to differentiate with respect to N right? So, I differentiate everything in the bracket with respect to N i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial N}$ but then what happens to the $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}}$ left over?

Comment: @DavidSmith $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}}=1$.

Comment: hmm I'm really close to understanding this whole problem now but why is $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}}=1$? is it because $N$ is a function of $N_A$? Sorry to bother you, this is the only question I have left regarding this! It's just that this is a new way of maths that I haven't come across often.

Comment: @DavidSmith $N=N_{A}+N_{B}$ so if you keep $N_{B}$ constant and differentiate this with respect to $N_{A}$ you get $1$.

Comment: @eranreches I have just read this thread and agree with most of what you have proven. My only question is, if we are using the idea that $\frac{\partial}{\partial N_A} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}} \frac{\partial}{\partial N}$ then how did the derivation yield the first term as $\ln \left(\frac{N_{A}}{N}\right)+1$? Surely using the product rule as the OP has mentioned, he kept N constant, right? and you're saying N is not constant in your post?

Comment: @vik1245 You still have some $N_{A}$'s in the expression you need to differentiate also. Write everything explicitly $\frac{\partial}{\partial N_{A}}\left[N_{A}\ln\left(\frac{N_{A}}{N_{A}+N_{B}}\right)+N_{B}\ln\left(\frac{N_{B}}{N_{A}+N_{B}}\right)\right]$ and differentiate.

Comment: @eranreches I think my comment wasn't well worded. If I differentiate partially with respect to $N_A$, my question is when does the chain rule $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_{A}} \frac{\partial}{\partial N}$ take place? If I differentiate explicitly with respect to partial $N_A$ I can't see when I would differentiate with respect to N.